# git bash ssh-keygen documentation

Tags: git, bash, documentation, ssh-keys

I have tried googling this, but I am having a hard time finding it. Where would I find official documentation for using the ssh-keygen command from a git bash from Windows? This is the bash that gets installed with msysgit. I want to know exactly what options it accepts and what they all mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ssh-keygen` installed by msysgit is probably the one from OpenSSH. Here is the [manual page for `ssh-keygen`](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-keygen&sektion=1). There are man pages for the [other OpenSSH commands](http://openssh.com/manual.html), too.